# I can't press right click and icons disappeared on RHEL6

Tags: linux, nautilus, rhel-6

I'm only left with the desktop. When I right click, I get no response. Another problem is that there's no menus or icons.

When I try to open Nautilus it doesn't start.

When I tried to open it from the terminal I get this error:

```
nautilus: error while loading shared libraries: libnautilus-extension.so.1:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: that error looks like RHEL is broken, and you'd need to nuke and reinstall

Comment: Are you still able to install software via command line?

Comment: If OP is able to install (for instance with yum), then it is (painfully) doable to reinstall the window manager, etc.  The likely cause of the problem is user error...

Comment: I can install and open any pplicatio nusing terminal